# Dragging Events Not Receiving If mouseEntered() Events Is Tracking by Cocoa App

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsevent

Working on a Cocoa App where the app needs to do two things in case - :

1) mouse entered or exited

2) mouse dragged files to the app

I have view A, 
view A is registered for receiving dragging events and
has tracking area for receiving mouse entered and exited events,

Issue is: 
If I drag files to the view A; view A receives the mouseEntered: event instead of draggingEntered: event.

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
   NSLog(@"draggingEntered called");
}


- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
   NSLog(@"mouseEntered called");
}
```

> 2018-02-05 14:08:58.273 XXX_APP [3420:119122] mouseEntered called
>
> 2018-02-05 14:08:58.273 XXX_APP [3420:119122] draggingEntered called

Issue is whenever I drag files to the view; It goes into the mouseEntered()
not into the mouseDragged().
Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confused, your console log shows both messages being displayed? Are you calling `[super mouseEntered:theEvent]`? If not, the event is going to get swallowed up and could be preventing the `draggingEntered:` method from being called.

Comment: @theeagle thing is when I drag files then it should only print draggingEntered called not mouseEntered because in this case another operation gets performed of mouseEntered

Comment: Oh ok, gotcha. You might want to look into `NSTrackingEnabledDuringMouseDrag`. From [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstrackingareaoptions/nstrackingenabledduringmousedrag), it sounds like you can make the distinction between the two events with this flag. Hope that helps!

Comment: Your title is misleading; the drag operations are being received, just not in the order you'd prefer with mouse tracking also enabled.

Comment: @vikramsingh Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: delaying the call is good idea but I thought there would be a good solution for this kind of requirement, I'll give it a try and let you know... thnx @Jon

Comment: @theeagle I looked into it and there is no way to find out the distinction between this two events. although thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong but I believe a drag operation is dependent on the mouse entering the view so if you're tracking mouse events, the `mouseEntered:` method will always be called first. That said, you can delay doing something with the `mouseEntered:` event giving the view time to see if it is followed by a drag operation and, if so, cancel the `mouseEntered:` call. This can be done using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` (using a very brief delay that is probably not noticeable to the user) and `cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:` like so:

```
- (void)updateTrackingAreas {
    [super updateTrackingAreas];
    for (NSTrackingArea *trackingArea in self.trackingAreas) {
        [self removeTrackingArea:trackingArea];
    }
    [self addTrackingArea:[[NSTrackingArea alloc] initWithRect:self.bounds options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited | NSTrackingActiveAlways) owner:self userInfo:nil]];
}

- (void)_mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"mouseEntered");
    //do something...
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)event {
    //pause 0.05 seconds before acting on this event,
    //giving the view time to see if a draggingEntered: event is triggered
    [self performSelector:@selector(_mouseEntered:) withObject:event afterDelay:0.05];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"mouseExited");
    //do something...
}

//assumes you've registered for drag events (e.g., in init):
//  [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    //cancel pending _mouseEntered: call:
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self]; 
    NSLog(@"draggingEntered");
    NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    return (([pasteboard.types containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]) ? NSDragOperationLink : NSDragOperationNone);
}

- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender {
    NSPasteboard *pasteboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];
    if ([pasteboard.types containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]) {
        for (NSString *filePath in [pasteboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType]) {
            NSLog(@"dropped file: %@", filePath);
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: as you have suggested @jon this worked like a charm. thank you.